# Calculate the amount of items that would fit in the viewable area of a Listbox in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, tk-toolkit

I'm having trouble finding out the number of Listbox items that would fit just in the viewable Listbox area, so that you don't need to scroll down. 
Sorry if this is trivial, I'm having difficulty figuring this one out.

I've wrote a small example to illustrate my problem:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFont import Font

myfont=Font(family='Times', size=12)

a=Listbox(activestyle='dotbox', font=myfont)
a.insert(END, *xrange(100))
a.pack(side='left', fill=BOTH, expand=1)

mainloop()
```

so now I have a listbox, but only some of its items are visible. How do I figure out how many can I fit without going outside the viewable area? Any insights would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of a tkFont height is stored in the `linespace` metric, which is accessible via the `metrics()` method -

```
myfont.metrics()['linespace']
#returns 19 for myfont as initiated in the question
```

The height of the Listbox widget is retrievable via `winfo_height()`. In total -

```
visible_lines= a.winfo_height()/myfont.metrics()['linespace']
```

Resource - 
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/fonts.html

Answer (score 0):

Listboxes have an option `height`, which is the number of lines of text to display.  The default is 10.  Since you leave the default as is, your box displays 10 lines, containing '0' to '9'.  I discovered this by checking http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html, which I use routinely.  It only has a few errors.

Comment: But how do I know how many lines fit in a specific viewable area? Let's say the user resizes the window or changes the font, how do I know, for a given Listbox size, how many items fit in without scrolling?